# Using normal distribution to approximate binomial

Tags: probability, statistics

> 1. From a shipment of cars, 100 are sampled at random and tested.
> 2. The shipment is rejected if 12 or more of the cars fail the test.
> 3. Assume that any given car in the shipment has a 15% chance of failing the test.

Use a normal distribution to approximate the probability that the shipment will be rejected.

So if $n=100\,,\ p=.15$, then $\mu = 15$ and $\sigma = 3.571$.

Am I on the right track here ?.

Comment: So far so good.

Comment: So when I find $P(X<12)$, should I subtract that value from 1? This part always confuses me. I can't wrap my head around the wording.

Comment: Well, the wording is a bit odd.  After all, the mean is $15$ so there is a greater than $50\%$ chance that the shipment is to be cancelled...seems harsh.    But, to your question, yes.  You want $P(X>12)=1-P(X<12)$

Comment: Also, not sure if you are expected to use any sort of [continuity adjustment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction) for the endpoint.  Always an issue when you are approximating something discrete via something continuous.

Comment: @lulu You mean $P(X\geq 12)=1-P(X< 12)$ ?

Comment: @callculus It's a continuous distribution....$P(X=12)=0$.

Comment: @lulu But the cars are not continuous.

Comment: @callculus  But $P$ is continuous.  The real issue I think you are getting at is the continuity correction, and that should be taken seriously.  I would compute $1-P(X<12.5)$ instead of what the OP has done.  Or I'd use a Poisson process instead of a normal.

Comment: @lulu It might be better to look at $P(X \le 11.5)$ and $P(X \gt 11.5)$, as it says "$12$ or more"

Comment: @Henry  You are exactly correct, it's $11.5$, not $12.5$.  Just to illustrate if I do it exactly (via binomial distributions) I get $0.836513842$.  If I do it with the normal and your $11.5$ value I get $0.836485967$, an excellent approximation indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you should remember to use a **continuity correction**.  You seek the probability of the event $X\ge12$, which is the same as $X> 11$.   Do we use $11$ or $12$ here?  The answer is: use the average, $11.5$.  That's a continuity correction, done because you're using a continuous approximation to a discrete distribution.